# Normal distribution with abs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Hello all my teacher give me an exercice in probability with absolut value can someone help me ? Thank you in advance.

So whe have X who follow the normal distribution law with (-1,4) in parameters and Y ~N (5,  o^2)

They request us to : 
1)Calculate P (|X-1|<2)
2) found the value of a when P (|X+1|>a)=3/4
3) whe supposed P (Y>6)=1/8  found o
4) deduce the value of  P (Y>7)

Thank u very much for ur help and sorry for my English

Comment: I think I understand the English, but not the notation. Is the second parameter of N the variance? What is `o^2`? In 1) is it $P(|X-1| < 2)^2?$ What is `3/4 3`? and what is `o 4`? Are you using `o` for $\sigma?$

Comment: Yes   I use o for sigma and 3/4 is the value of P (|X+1|>a)=3/4

Comment: And I can't found the a if you can help me please @bruceET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give a hint, but since it's homework you'll need to work it out yourself.

1) If ${\mid{X-1}\mid \lt 2}$, then ${-1 \lt X \lt 3}$. So you need ${P(-1\lt X\lt3)}$ given X is Normal. Can you think of a particular function of a distribution that adds up the probability at each possible x in that range? (Hint: how would you get the black region in the picture below?)

2) This logic is similar to the first.  For starters, it must be the case that a > 0 otherwise the probability would be 1 independent of any underlying distribution. Hence, it must be that ${X \gt -1 + a}$ or ${X \lt -1 -a)}$. (Hint: Note the symmetry about this *special* value -1. How would you calculate the points where the color changes from black to white in the picture below?)

3 and 4) Remember that if ${Y}$ is normal with ${(\mu, \sigma)}$ then ${\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}}$ is ${N(0, 1)}$. How can you use this fact to solve for ${\sigma}$ since you know also that ${\mu=5}$?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for ur help it help me very much I have found 0.3413 for the 1) and 0.8693 for sigma but I don't found the second question sir

Comment: By the way this is not homework but just training exercice for the exam and unfortunately I have some difficulties in stat :') and no problem when you help me I remake the exercice alone :)

Comment: For number 2, note that mu = -1. This means that you have X < mu -a or X > mu + a... This is symetric about mu... What can you do with the two sums given to you by Madhav Nakar knowing this symmetry is true?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following hints may help:
$$P(|X-1|<2) = P(-2 < X -1 < 2) = P(-1 < X < 3)$$
$$P(|X+1|>a)= P(X+1>a) + P(X+1<-a) = P(X>a-1) + P(X<-a-1)= \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you for ur help it help me very much I have found 0.3413 for the 1) and 0.8693 for sigma but I don't found the second question sir